# http://127.0.0.1:9890/ubersvn is not responding

Tags: svn, ubersvn

`http://127.0.0.1:9890/ubersvn` is not responding though I am able to commit changes through RAD. I can access the repository pages through IE with same IP. `http://127.0.0.1:9890/reporitory`

2 weeks ago I installed SVN on my machine and created users and repositories. When I try to access the server to add one more user `http://127.0.0.1:9890/ubersvn` using the same URL the page displays the message *"Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage"*.

I don't know what to do? How can I add a user?

Answer (score 0):

I restarted the server, but it shows error message as its running already. but again i tried with same URl it is working fine. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The uberSVN admin interface runs on port 9890 by default but the SVN server actually runs on 9880 by default.

Are you sure you're hitting the right port?

The reason I ask is because it would be impossible to run both the uberSVN admin interface and the SVN Apache server on the same port, which your initial post suggests you are trying to do.